# Is it save to assume sqlite3_exec database pointer does not change its value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, sqlite

The declaration of `sqlite3_exec` is using a non-const pointer to non-const sqlite3 object

```
sqlite3_exec( sqlite3* db, const char* command, ... )
```

This is reasonable, since the function will need a pointer to traverse the database and the data within can be modified by the command passed to `sqlite3_exec`.

However, is it save to assume, that `sqlite3_exec` does *always* return with the `sqlite3* db` storing the same address as before? Even if errors occur?

The reason why this question arises, is because I try to write a C++ wrapper, using RAII (most likely following the rule of zero). The most natural way to represent the pointer to the database is therefore a `std::unique_ptr`. Obviously I cannot pass it directly to `sqlite3_exec`, but I could do this:

```
sqlite3_exec( myUniquePointer.get(), ... );
```

Alternatively one could release the pointer and transfer the ownership back to the `unique_ptr`, but this is less elegant. So the way via `get()` would be preferred, but therefore the pointer would not be allowed to have a different state after the execution, because the `unique_ptr` could not track it and would point to an inappropriate address.

Comment: FYI, I know why you did it, but people around here tend to get very cranky if you put both the "C" and "C++" tags on the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused about the way the language works.  It is *not possible* for a function that takes a pointer-to-*anything* argument to modify the *pointer itself*.

No matter what `sqlite3_exec` does, therefore, the value of `db` in the caller (the "address") will be unchanged.

(The functions `sqlite3_close` and `sqlite3_close_v2` will *invalidate* the database pointer, by deallocating the memory that it points to, but even then, the bit representation of the pointer is unchanged and it's possible for a correct program to observe that fact.)

Comment: So true... just didn't see the obvious! But I know why I prefer C++ over C =).